# Automatically set tickInterval depending on labels width

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to set tickInterval automatically depending on axis labels width in highcharts?

In the first case tick interval is fine, but in the second it is too small. How can I set optimal interval for different sets of values?

[image: Optimal tick interval]

[image: tick interval must be bigger]

Comment: are you setting the tickintervals in those examples, or is that the default from Highcharts?  usually the default will work just fine if you leave it unspecified.  If you provide fiddle examples it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use tickPositioner, which allows to define dynamic ticks http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner